# Next.js An update to Image inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I created a basic NextJS app using create-next-app then added Jest for testing. However, I am getting the error "An update to Image inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)" in my Jest test. It seems to be something to do with the Image component of NextJS updating after render, but I'm not quite sure what's the best way to test with it. I've included the Jest test and the problematic part of the component here:

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
      Powered by{' '}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render, act } from '@testing-library/react'
import { axe } from 'jest-axe'

import Home from '@/pages/index'

it('should demonstrate this matcher`s usage with react testing library', async () => {
  const { container } = render(<Home/>)

  const results = await axe(container)
  
  expect(results).toHaveNoViolations()
})
```

The error message also points to code at `node_modules/next/client/image.tsx:353:3` being problematic, and looking at the source, that part seems to be a useLayoutEffect hook in the Image component...

[image: node_modules/next/client/image.tsx:353]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Followed the solution mentioned at [this article](https://www.benmvp.com/blog/avoiding-react-act-warning-when-accessibility-testing-next-link-jest-axe/) and it worked.

1. Install react-intersection-observer
2. In the Jest config (jest.config.js):

- Add react-intersection-observer/test-utils' to the setupFilesAfterEnv
- Create a jest.setupFiles.js and add to setupFiles in the in the customJestConfig

```js
{
...
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setupFiles.js'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/jest.setup.js',
    'react-intersection-observer/test-utils',
  ],
...
}
```

3. In jest.setupFiles add:

```js
import { defaultFallbackInView } from 'react-intersection-observer'

global.IntersectionObserver = jest.fn()
defaultFallbackInView(false)
```

And the error should go away. :)